# Qual é a diferença entre ListView e RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-recyclerview

Qual diferença entre `ListView` e `RecyclerView` no Android?

A partir de qual APi a `RecyclerView` está disponível?

É válido usar a `RecyclerView` e não a `ListView`?

Comment: A quem possa interessar: usar RecyclerView em vez de uma GridView, pelo menos atualmente, vai te dar uma dor de cabeça enorme caso você queira o comportamento de tamanho de colunas automático (auto_fit).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O RecyclerView é uma nova (mas nem tanto) view que veio para substituir o ListView e o GridView.

De acordo com sua [documentação](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html), trata-se de um widget mais avançado e eficiente, quando comparado aos seus antecessores, e que apresenta diversas simplificações para suportar animações e diferentes disposições de elementos.

Para oferecer todas estas otimizações, a Google decidiu simplificar o elemento. Pode parecer estranho, mas o RecyclerView possui um nível de responsabilidade menor quando comparado ao ListView. Em teoria, o widget é apenas um container que encapsula um LayoutManager e um ItemAnimator, e que se comunica com um Adapter, mais precisamente, um RecyclerView.Adapter.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mas a forma de ter que criar um adapter, popular ele, depois setar no ListView, continua a mesma pro RecyclerView?

Comment: Exato, a diferença é mais performance mesmo. Ao fazer cache da View não é necessário acionar o método findViewById inúmeras vezes toda vez que o usuário rolar pela lista, como resultado é exibida uma lista muito mais fluída, pois as células são recicladas

Comment: O `RecyclerView` exige a implementação no adapter e no `ViewHolder` da reciclagem dos items. Isso está embutido nela e não pode ser evitado. No `ListView` esse paradigma é opcional. Dá um pouquinho mais de trabalho usar o `RecyclerView`, mas é muito mais eficiente e, particularmente, não uso mais `ListView` nem em casos triviais.

Answer (score 16):

> Qual diferença entre ListView e RecyclerView no Android?

São duas as diferenças entre a [ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) e a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html):

1. A *RecyclerView* é agnóstica em relação a onde as *views* são colocadas,  como são movidas e como esse movimento é animado. Isso é conseguido movendo essas responsabilidades para um [LayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html) e um [ItemAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.html), permitindo que o mesmo *adapter* represente visualmente os dados de diferentes formas:

   - verticalmente, como a *ListView*.
   - horizontalmente
   - grelha uniforme, como o *GridView*
   - grelha com elementos de diferentes dimensões(*staggered grids*)
   - outra qualquer, use a imaginação e [implemente](http://wiresareobsolete.com/2014/09/building-a-recyclerview-layoutmanager-part-1/) o respectivo *LayoutManager*.
     <sub>Fonte: [Building a RecyclerView LayoutManager – Part 3](http://wiresareobsolete.com/2015/02/recyclerview-layoutmanager-3/)</sub>
     [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

   Essa diferença é evidenciada na forma como cada uma é inicializada:

   - ListView:

     ```
     listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
     ```
   - RecyclerView:

     ```
     recyclerView.setAdapter(myRecyclerAdapter);
     recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
     recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
     ```
2. Usa um tipo de *adapter*([Recycler.Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html)) que implementa o padrão *ViewHolder*. 
   É usado um objecto [ViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html) para armazenar cada uma das *views* do *layout*, para que possam ser imediatamente acedidas sem a necessidade de usar `findViewById()` repetidamente.
   Na *ListView* essa [implementação](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) era opcional.

> A partir de qual APi a RecyclerView está disponível?

A *RecyclerView* surgiu com o Android 5 mas está disponível para versões anteriores através da [v7 recyclerview library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v7-recyclerview).

> É válido usar a RecyclerView e não a ListView?

O uso de qualquer uma é válido.

A *RecyclerView* não é propriamente um substituto da *ListView*. Ela é uma nova abordagem, mais flexível, de fornecer uma vista limitada de um grande conjunto de dados.

O uso da ListView em situações de listas imutáveis, como lista de opções por exemplo, parece-me perfeitamente adequado.