# Erro RecyclerView: No layout manager attached

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Não consegui achar o erro.

minha activity:

```
private AdapterPacientes adapterPacientes;
private static MVP.Presenter presenter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_pacientes);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    if (presenter == null)
        presenter = new Presenter();
    presenter.setActivity(this);
    presenter.retrivePacientes( savedInstanceState );
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    RecyclerView lista = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    lista.setHasFixedSize(true);

    adapterPacientes = new AdapterPacientes(presenter.getPacientes());
    lista.setAdapter(adapterPacientes);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putParcelableArrayList(KEY_PACIENTE, presenter.getPacientes());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void refreshAdapter() {
    adapterPacientes.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

// ...
```

erro que aparece no log

[image: erro do log]

Fiquei mais de duas horas pesquisando mas não achei o porque...
A estrutura do código esta no padrão MVP.

Os dados estão sendo trazidos e a `arraylist` esta sendo populada corretamente.

desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O erro é esclarecedor: Nenhum LayoutManager associado.

Uma das [diferenças entre a RecyclerView e ListView](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159963/2541) é que a RecyclerView é agnóstica em relação à forma como o itens são dispostos visualmente.
Essa responsabilidade é desempenhada pelo LayoutManager associado ela.

Então, o que falta é associar um à RecyclerView. A API do Android disponibiliza vários [LayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html) e você mesmo pode criar o seu.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    RecyclerView lista = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    lista.setHasFixedSize(true);

    //Atribuir LayoutManager
    lista.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    adapterPacientes = new AdapterPacientes(presenter.getPacientes());
    lista.setAdapter(adapterPacientes);
}
```

Comment: Nossa... Deu até vergonha de não ter visto que não declarei o LayoutManager... Por isso que quando a mente começa a embaralhar é melhor dar uma parada, dormir um pouco ou jogar um game... Aí da um reset na mente e pensamos melhor! Rsrs

Answer (score 0):

Olá, no meu caso eu fiz a associação do LayoutManager, mas continua dando o erro!!

Método para listar os dados do firebase

```
public void listarContatos(){
        //Listagem de Contatos
        contatosRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Contato contatos = dataSnapshot.getValue(Contato.class);
                listaContatos.add(contatos);

                Adapter adaptador = new Adapter(listaContatos);

                RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                listViewContatos.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                listViewContatos.setHasFixedSize(true);
                listViewContatos.setAdapter(adaptador);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {


            }
        });
}insira o código aqui
```

Classe Adapter

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder>{

private List <Contato> listaContatos;

public Adapter(List<Contato> lista) {
    this.listaContatos = lista;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemLista = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_contatos, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemLista);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Contato contatos = listaContatos.get(position);

    holder.nome.setText(contatos.getNome());
    holder.telefone.setText(contatos.getTelefone());
    holder.celular.setText(contatos.getCelular());
    holder.email.setText(contatos.getEmail());
    holder.status.setImageResource(contatos.getImageStatus());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return this.listaContatos.size();
}

//MINHA VIEW HOLDER ****************************************************************************
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView nome;
    TextView telefone;
    TextView celular;
    TextView email;
    ImageView status;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        nome = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textNome);
        telefone = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTelefone);
        celular = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTelefone);
        email = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textEmail);
        status = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageStatus);
    }
}
```

}

Classe Modelo

public class Contato {

```
private String nome, celular, telefone, email;
private int imageStatus;

private Contato contato;




public Contato() {


}

public Contato(String nome, String celular, String telefone, String email) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.celular = celular;
    this.telefone = telefone;
    this.email = email;
}

public Contato(Contato contato) {
    this.contato = contato;
}

public void salvar(){

    FirebaseAuth autenticacao = ConfigFirebase.getFirebaseAutenticacao();
    String idUsuario = autenticacao.getCurrentUser().getUid().toString();

    DatabaseReference firebase = ConfigFirebase.getFirebase();
    firebase.child("contatos")
            .child(idUsuario)
            .push()
            .setValue(this);

}


public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getCelular() {
    return celular;
}

public void setCelular(String celular) {
    this.celular = celular;
}

public String getTelefone() {
    return telefone;
}

public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
    this.telefone = telefone;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@Exclude
public int getImageStatus() {
    return imageStatus;
}

public void setImageStatus(int imageStatus) {
    this.imageStatus = imageStatus;
}
```

}